# @Validated outside of @RequestMapping

Tags: spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

Is it possible to run @Validated after the @RequestMapping method has started?  The reason is that I need to modify the @ModelAttribute before actually validating it.

Ideally something like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doSomething",
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
public final String DoSomething(
        @ModelAttribute(value = "myobject") final MyObject myobject) {
   //.... do some processing on myobject
   //.... now validate
   BindingResult bindingResult = validate(myobject);
   //...
```

And a method like this

```
private final BindingResult validate(
        @Validated(value = {Group1.class, Group2.class}) MyObject myobject) {

  return bindingResult //somehow return a BindingResult
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your own custom Validator

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-binder

Comment: That does not appear to support Validation Groups

Comment: you didn't ask you want validation group :)

Comment: It is part of the question `@Validated(value = {Group1.class, Group2.class}`